# Signing iOS application when publishing an update to an existing app on the app store

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm a mobile developer and I'm trying to update a App which is already exist on the App store. My company CTO added me as admin on Appstore iTunes connect. I'm very confused of all the details regarding certificates & provisioning profiles. So my question is: Do I have to create a new certificate and/or new provisioning profile associated with my apple ID? Can't I use the already existing distribution provisioning profile?
So can someone specify what do I need in order to successfully sign & archive my iOS application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case first, you need to check some things before launching the app

store.

- First, check whether you have the related certificates or not in your
     the system's keychain if not

  a. ask for the certificates who created it, you just cannot download 
         it from the apple developer account directly.

  b. if there is no option to get the certificates then you need to 
         create one for yourself just create one and re-edit your 
          provisioning profile again with the newly created certificate

For provisioning profile, you can just direct download it from developer account.

Answer (score 1):

For the certificate file, you can ask the person who created before to export it (from keychain) and then you can use the existing file. Or you have to create a new one.

Note: Depend on your account entity type, apple limited number of the certificate file can be created.

Be careful with APNS certificate file, it may affect directly to your app remote notification.

For provisioning file, it goes with certificate file above:

- if you can use the existing certificate file then you can keep using current provisioning file by download it.
- If you create a new certificate file, you have to create new provisioning file or edit current one. (I often edit the existing file when adding a new device or change certificate file).